# XPath to select element

Tags: xml, xpath, element

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a>
   <b>6.89<c>45</c></b>
</a>
```

I tried //b getting wrong result http://xpather.com/LwG6si6t

Desired Output to get `6.89` only.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `//b/text()` for that sample or `//b/text()[1]` if there can be more text after the `c` element.